# Count tweets using a hashtag

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter

I'm developing a Twitter App and have a problem I cannot resolve. Could you help me please?
The app is for a promotion for a brand. We need to count every tweet using a hashtag and give the author of tweet #50000 a price. How can we take that data from Twitter API and identify tweet #50000? Thanks for your help!

We use PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Please share what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking into [phirehose](http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/) which will allow you to obtain the tweets. You can also use the [Ruby Twitter Gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) which is fairly well documented and seems to be easy to use if you are comfortable with ruby.

Comment: downvoted for Ruby reference.  OP plainly states they use PHP & MySQL

Answer (score 1):

**this php source code for get count hashtag(#) twitter**

```
<?php
   global $total, $hashtag;
   //$hashtag = '#supportvisitbogor2011';
   $hashtag = '#australialovesjustin';
   $total = 0;
   function getTweets($hash_tag, $page) {
      global $total, $hashtag;
      $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&';
      $url .= 'page='.$page;    
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $json = curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);
      //echo "<pre>";    
      //$json_decode = json_decode($json);
      //print_r($json_decode->results);

      $json_decode = json_decode($json);        
      $total += count($json_decode->results);    
      if($json_decode->next_page){
         $temp = explode("&",$json_decode->next_page);        
         $p = explode("=",$temp[0]);                
         getTweets($hashtag,$p[1]);
      }        
   }

   getTweets($hashtag,1);
   echo $total;
?>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I was looking this up last night. You can request the URL ie. http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag

(Here's the docs page http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search)

And on say a 5 minute cron script, keep a record of the last tweet ID you got, passing that to the search URL since_id parameter, while also keeping a count of how many tweets you have counted, optionally storing each tweet in a table for reference... that's my 2 cents

Comment: It will list only recently tagged posts... he needs to set up cron job to monitor these tweets, even then it is very unlikely that 50000 will actually be 50000 tweet...

Comment: The streaming API will be much more accurate, as it will return tweets as they are written. The search API goes through old tweets and I don't think that is what the @abotella wants to achieve.